# Delete notifications from API

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby, backend

I want to enable notification deletion with swipe. I've successfully implemented the code that deletes a row with a comment, but I can't figure out what to do to delete it from the server.

Here's API info:

```
  desc 'delete notifications'
  params do
    requires :notification_ids, type: Array
  end
  delete 'notifications/remove', root: :notifications, each_serializer:  NotificationSerializer do
    require_authentication!
    NotificationLogic.delete_notifications params[:notification_ids], current_user
    current_user.notifications
```

Here's the method I've made for deleting notifications:

```
-(void)deleteNotificationWithId:(NSArray*)ids withCompletionHandler:    (DeleteNotificationCompletionHandler)handler
{
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

[_objectManager deleteObject:nil
                        path:@"user/notifications/remove"
                       parameters:nil
                     success:
 ^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
 {
     handler(YES, mappingResult.firstObject, nil);

                     } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                         if (operation.HTTPRequestOperation.response.statusCode == 401 && !_secondTry)
                         {
                             [weakSelf relogin:^{
                                 [weakSelf deleteNotificationWithId:ids withCompletionHandler:handler];
                             }];
                             return;
                     }
                         handler(NO, nil, error);
                     }];
}
```

and here's NotificationTableView:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    //Remove item in array
    [self.notifications removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Also remove that row from the table view with an animation
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [[Api sharedInstance]deleteNotificationWithId: arr
withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL succes, Message      *response, NSError *error) {
           if (succes) {
 [Utils     alert:NSLocalizedString(@"Notification deleted", nil)];
                                } else {
                                    [Utils alert:error.pop_message];
                                }
                            }];
}
}

#pragma mark TableView Data Source

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return self.notifications.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NotificationTableViewCell* cell = [self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NotificationTableViewCell"];
[cell configureCellWithNotification:self.notifications[indexPath.row]];

return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath{
Notification* not = self.notifications[indexPath.row];
[self.notificationDelegate notificationTapped:not];
}
```

When I swipe to delete, I get this error:

```
E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:215 DELETE 'http://xxx/user/notifications/remove' (422 Unprocessable Entity / 0 objects) [request=0.0470s mapping=0.0000s total=0.0497s]: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1004 "RequestValidationErrors" UserInfo={RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey=(
RequestValidationErrors
), NSLocalizedDescription=RequestValidationErrors}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says you are contacting the API, but not sending any objects.  In looking at your code, I would say this is the problem area.

```
[_objectManager deleteObject:nil
                        path:@"user/notifications/remove"
                  parameters:nil
```

According to the API you need an array of ids.  (`requires :notification_ids, type: Array`)  You have the array of ids in `ids` you need to pass to the API.  My guess not being able to see the docs is you need to change the above code to:

```
[_objectManager deleteObject:nil
                        path:@"user/notifications/remove"
                  parameters:ids
```

Comment: "parameters" is of type NSDictionary, not NSArray

Comment: OK, but my point remains, you need to pass the `ids` array to the API somehow.  Since it is a `NSDistionary` maybe you have to create it and put the `ids` array in it.  What does the API doc say?

Comment: I didn't get any API docs, I thought what I have should be enough to implement this function

Comment: Somehow you have to tell the server which ids to delete.  If that is all you have I would try passing a `NSDictionary` which `notification_ids` as the key and `ids` as the value and see what happens.

Comment: You were right! I added the NSDictionary as a parameter and the server got the right request. It delets notifications, but I only hard-code arrays representing notifications now. Any idea how I can point to the notification being tapped inside NotificationTableView? I edited the original post adding the code for TableView Data Source and TableView Delegate, if that helps.

Comment: Great, glad it helped.  You would be better to ask another question with the problems you are having with the NotificationTable view with only the relevant code. If the original question you had has been solved by this answer, please accept the answer to remove it from the unanswered queue.